# Rails Will_paginate: Include parents?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, will-paginate

lets say I have the following models:
Grandpa, Dad, Child

Where Grandpa has_many Dads, and Dad has_many Children.

I'm displaying Children using will_paginate. Is there any way to include Grandpas so I can display their names? I know I can include children, but am having problems including parents instead...

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can display Grandpas using, children.dad.grandpa
or
You can query children including grandpa like below

Children.find(:all, :include => {:dad => :grandpa})